# Calling this.function inside of jquery context

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype, this

I am trying to call a function via `this` reference inside of jquery scope:

```
var Person = function(){

    this.hello = function(){
        console.log("hello!");
    }

    this.jump = function(){
        $('.jump').on('click', function(){
            this.hello();
        });
    }

}
```

Then I do:

```
var p = new Person();
```

When I click over the `.jump` element, the console prints an error describing that `hello is not a function`. I am not sure what is happening here,  I am assumming that `this` is trying to call a function inside of jquery (not sure about it).

So, googling a little bit I found the [Jquery.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) function that could be helpfull in my situation, but every time I try to understand it my head want to explote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$.proxy()` like so:

```
var Person = function(){

    this.hello = function(){
        console.log("hello!");
    }

    this.jump = function(){
        $('.jump').on(
            'click',
            $.proxy(
                function() {
                    this.hello();
                },
                this
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Passing `this` as the 2nd argument to `$.proxy()` sends that context as the value of `this` inside the function defined in the first argument.

Comment: I consider this answer elegant.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
var self = this;


 this.jump = function(){
        $('.jump').on('click', function(){
            self.hello();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

when you refer to "this" inside onclick, by default this refers to the DOM element found in the value of event.target

```
$('.jump').on('click', function(event) {
     this.hello() /// <<-- this == event.target =~ $('.jump')
}
```

so, fortunately, you can use a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)

```
var self = this;
this.jump = function(){
    $('.jump').on('click', function(){
        self.hello();
    });
}
```

Comment: In your first example, it should be clarified that by default `this` refers to the DOM element found in the value of `event.target`.